# Multiple DetailViewControllers using a UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

Currently, I have a SplitViewController with a MasterViewController and a DetailViewController. I was wondering whether there's a way to have more DetailViewControllers. Right now I have a list of items in the tableView to the left and if you click on them, they go to a fullscreen view. How can I keep I have it to show inside the panel to the right of the splitview when clicked on instead? So with reference to this image - how can I get my view to display like the colour yellow in the detail section? Right now when I click on my equivalent of "yellow" - the colour yellow is shown fullscreen, and not as the detail. http://2uagoo1zzsoo4bcz3347bs2y.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Image003.png

extra info:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc: UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newViewController") as! UINavigationController

        self.presentViewController (vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else if indexPath.row == 3 {

        let storyboardTwo: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vcTwo: UINavigationController = storyboardTwo.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newViewController4") as! UINavigationController

        self.presentViewController(vcTwo, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: I can't really understand your question, I've worked on a similar project but I don't quite get what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Now if I click on the left pane items (the color names), it opens a new view. I want it to show beside it, in the detailview. Not in a seperate view by itself. Clearer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use the show showDetailViewController method:

Presents the specified view controller as the secondary view controller of the split view interface.

```
func showDetailViewController(_ vc: UIViewController,
                   sender sender: AnyObject?)
```

So in your case it would be used more like this.  In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function:

```
{
    let vc:UIViewController
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        vc: UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newViewController") as! UINavigationController   



    } else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        let storyboardTwo: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       vc: UINavigationController = storyboardTwo.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newViewController4") as! UINavigationController

    }else {
     // handle this case
        vc = ...
    }
    // Grab the Split View Controller 
    let splitVC = // get Split View Controller
    splitVC.showDetailViewController(vc,sender:nil)
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks. So how do I trigger this function after a cell is tapped? Could you explain some more with reference to my code above, please? :D

Comment: If I understand correctly, instead of presenting the view controller, get the split view controller and have it call this method, something like this:  splitVC.showDetailViewController(vcTwo, sender:nil)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. and vcTwo? Must I change that? :)

Comment: Sorry Jbryson, I really appreciate your help - I'm a novice. I assume this is very wrong:   override func showDetailViewController(vc: GreetingsTableViewController, sender: AnyObject?) {
        
        let vcTwo: UINavigationController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newViewController") as! UINavigationController
        
        
     GreetingsTableViewController.showDetailViewController(vcTwo, sender:nil)
        
        
      
    }

Comment: Done. Thank you very very much jbryson!! :D Hope I can help you someday haha